# Are there any libraries (or using GD2 or Image Magick) to allow the upload and processing of EPS or Vector files?

Tags: php, pdf, symfony1, eps, gd2

I need to allow for scaling a user uploaded logo to different sizes for different formats, are there any libraries (included or extra) that allow for the procesing of EPS files or high res artwork for this purpose?

Comment: what do you call "processing"?

Comment: I was under the impression ImageMagick could handle this.

Comment: As Tom says, ImageMagick can do this - either via the CLI tools or the PHP extension.

Answer (score 0):

If you've built PHP with ext/java and can deal with SVG, PEAR's [XML_svg2image](http://pear.php.net/package/XML_svg2image/) is an interface to [Apache Batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/)'s rasterizer.  It's a little abandoned though, and has been collecting dust since 2002.

Batik itself is scriptable though, so automating conversion via command-line or external process shouldn't be *too* hairy if you don't want to / can't recompile PHP or deal with dead code.